# Targeting a nested <a> element and removing its href attribute using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a little help with removing the href element of the below 'a' element:

```
<div class="carousel__tape-item js-product">
    <div class="sale-content__cell">
        <a href="www.website.com"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my attempt but it doesn't work:

```
var a = $(".carousel__tape-item .sale-content__cell");
a.find("a").removeAttr("href");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `$(".sale-content__cell a").removeAttr('href');`

Comment: Your code is correct. It should work fine. There is some other problem.

Comment: Are you calling it before the element exists on the page? I think you need to give more details on how you are calling this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the multiple selector syntax for jquery

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel__tape-item.js-product').find('a').removeAttr('href');
});`

See it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/ahc1uLdj/